# Java (Regex) - Get all words in a sentence

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to split a java string into an array of words.  Let's say the string is:

```
"Hi!! I need to split this string, into a serie's of words?!"
```

At the moment I'm tried using this `String[] strs = str.split("(?!\\w)")` however it keeps symbols such as ! in the array and it also keeps strings like "Hi!" in the array as well.  The string I am splitting will always be lowercase.  What I would like is for an array to be produced that looks like:
`{"hi", "i", "need", "to", "split", "this", "string", "into", "a", "serie's", "of", "words"}` - Note the apostrophe is kept.

How could I change my regex to not include the symbols in the array?

Apologies, I would define a word as a sequence of alphanumeric characters only but with the ' character inclusive if it is in the above context such as "it's", not if it is used to a quote a word such as "'its'".  Also, in this context "hi," or "hi-person" are not words but "hi" and "person" are.  I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: What is defined as a word? There are at least 2 different definition for it: non-whitespace continuous sequence, or a sequence of letters + digits.

Comment: What about `he said 'yes'` => keep or remove the quote?

Comment: Unless you know what a "word" is (well, there can be so-long-that-it-should-not-have-been-allowed-to-be-connected-with-hyphens words, or numbers 34.24, or something like 2000$), there will be plenty of answers popping up that try to define a word for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove all `?!` symbols and then split into words

```
str = str.replaceAll("[!?,]", "");
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
```

Result:

`Hi, I, need, to, split, this, string, into, a, serie's, of, words`

Comment: I like your style, replace any special char 1st then split the string as word...I think that will do, I'll give it a try later...

Comment: @mutanic: There is not much difference from split along `"[!?,\\s]+"`. (The only difference is that the string may contain `!?,` at the beginning, and the result will have an empty string, but this may also happen if the string after replacement has space in front)

Answer (score 5):

Should work for what you want.

```
String line = "Hi!! I need to split this string, into a serie's of words?! but not '' or ''' word";
String regex = "([^a-zA-Z']+)'*\\1*";
String[] split = line.split(regex);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(split));
```

Gives

```
[Hi, I, need, to, split, this, string, into, a, serie's, of, words, but, not, or, word]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define a word as a sequence of non-whitespace characters (whitespace character as defined by `\s`), then you can split along space characters:

```
str.split("\\s+")
```

Note that `";.';.@#$>?>@4"`, `"very,bad,punctuation"`, and `"'goodbye'"` are words under the definition above.

Then the other approach is to define a word as a sequence of characters from a set of allowed characters. If you want to allow `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `'` as part of a word, you can split along everything else:

```
str.split("[^a-zA-Z']+")
```

This will still allow `"''''''"` to be defined as a word, though.

Comment: To be clear, this would not produce the requested output given the example input from the question.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to split on anything that is not a wordcharacter [a-zA-Z] and is not a '
This regex will do that "[^a-zA-Z']*\s*"
There will be a problem if the string contains a quote that is quoted in '

I usually use this  page for testing my regex'
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the characters you deem as "non-word" characters:

```
String[] strs = str.split("[,!? ]+");
```

Comment: Note that this also has the same problem, as it will allow `-----------` or `'''''''''''''` to be a word.

Comment: This will work with the string in the question. The OP would need to specify how single quotes would otherwise be treated

Comment: I don't mean to criticize your answer. Just that without a clear definition, simple regex solution will allow funny things to be classified as word.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `str.split("[\\s,?!]+")`. You can add whatever character you want to split with inside the brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]","").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

`replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]","")` method replaces all the characters which are not `a-z` or `A-Z` or `'` or a `whitespace` with nothing (`""`) and then `toLowerCase` method make all the chars returned from `replaceAll` method lower case. Finally we are `split`ting the string in terms of whitespace char. more readable one;

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z'\\s]","");
myString = myString.toLowerCase();
String[] strArr = myString.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: You might want to include a bit more information rather than a single line. I get that it might answer the question, but your answer is popping up in the "low quality" review queue. If enough people vote for deletion, it might be gone at some point.

Comment: Sorry, added an explanation in detail.