# Regex Java - splitting a string by all whitespaces and punctuation except apostrophes and dashes

Tags: java, regex

What is the correct regex to split a string for all punctuation and white space but still keep apostrophes and dashes? I know for spaces I can just use str.split(“\s+”).

Comment: Define punctuation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539484/java-regex-get-all-words-in-a-sentence

Comment: see upper link and it solution solve your problem